# Error while installing psycopg2 in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I tried to install psycopg2 as:
`pip install psycopg2`

It was giving error for `pg_config`. I checked some stackoverflow notes and installed PostgreSQL. Added the path of `pg_config` in `$PATH`.

Now it is giving the below error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libpq.lib'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried reinstall without pip?

`sudo apt-get install python3-psycopg2`

**EDIT: Since you're on windows:**

You can try this if you're using python 2.7:

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win64-py27#egg=psycopg2
```

If you're using python 3.4:

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win64-py34#egg=psycopg2
```

More info [here](https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows).

If you prefer, you can download the installer (.exe) and install it.
You can find it [here](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/).

Comment: I tried: it says: 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  I removed sudo and tried again.. It says:  'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Are you logged as root?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt realize that you're on Windows.

Comment: Yes.. I am on Windows... not on Linux.

Comment: Tried that... getting error....  Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git C:\Users\SOGUPTA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6qr9tq3h\p
sycopg2
Cannot find command 'git'..... Do I need to change anything in $PATH?

Comment: I am using Python 3.7

Comment: You probably have to add the git binary path to the $PATH.
Everything of dev stuff in windows is more complicated. I'd suggest you to use linux subsystem inside windows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.... I was using Python 3.7 version. Looks like the latest stable version of psycopg2 (2.7.4) is not yet supported on Python 3.7. It is supported till 3.6

I downgraded my python to 3.6.5 in Anaconda and also to 2.7.15 through PyCharm. I was able to install psycopg2 in both and use them.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2
in release history and select the version you want to download.

There will be a table with files and the versions of python that can be compatible with the selected version.

Now download the wheel file that matches your system configuration(mac/linux/win-32/win-64)

I did this and was able to download the package.

For `windows10(64-bit)`, download `psycopg2-2.7.7-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (998.5 kB)`, in case you have selected 2.7.7

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users, to install the `psycopg2` without any errors first install  Python 3.7.4 version and then install `psycopg2` using command `pip install psycopg2` as it worked complete fine with me. I think there is some issue in Python 3.8.0 version onwards because while installing `psycopg` it is showing an error in setup wheels.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are here in 2020, this is a problem with version 3.8 of python. I had the issue recently. Try using virtualenv so that you can use lower versions of python in your workspace until psycopg2 is supported fully on Python version 3.8

Comment: This question was asked in 2018, before Python 3.8 was even in alpha.